# ApplicationWindow footer width controlled

Tags: qt, qml, footer, applicationwindow

I'm using `ApplicationWindow` in `main.qml`, and using `StackLayout` to call all the qml windows and navigate through them as needed (e.g. pageOne, pageTwo, ...).

As shown in the image below, I created a vertical TabBar which is always present regardless of which qml window/page is called. I want to create a **footer** in `ApplicationWindow` to view data as app current version. I want to control the footer width to be anchored left of TabBar, but the footer width fills the total width of the `ApplicationWindow` and pushing the TabBar up, causing undesired design.

Is there a way to cotrol `ApplicationWindow` footer width and anchoring it to TabBar? any suggestions are welcome.

[image]

---

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Just ignore ApplicationWindow's footer (if not set it will become zero height) and make your Footer part of the contentItem's layout.